# Send email every 10 minutes when there is a connection failure

Tags: java

I have a connection with a third party and most of the time that is working fine. But when the connection doesn’t work I need to send an email with an external service, but this email should only be send once every 10 minutes, while the connection isn’t working. The connection is used at least every 30 seconds, so it’s fine to wait for someone uses the connection. My question now is how can I check if the 10 minutes are past, so I can send another email about the failed connection.

I was thinking of several solutions, but I think that there are better ones.

**public static AtomicReference**

*We can set a static variable with the last data that the email has been send, this one should be save for multiple requests.*

**Static variable**

*Same idea as the AtomicReference, but this isn’t save for multiple requests.*

**Database entry**

*Add a database entry with the date of the last time that the email was send. I think this is a little bit overkill, but it’s nice that you have a history of the failures of that connection, although it’s not necessary to have this history.*

If you have better ideas, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your environment?  Do you have to send the e-mail from Java, or can you have an external task that monitors the connection?

Comment: An external mail service will send the email

Comment: Yes, but the environment in which you're checking for the connection?

Comment: You can use static volatile reference and synchronized section of code to send e-mail. But if you are in clustered environnement, database could be a solution or clustered shared memory (ex : memcached)

Comment: @roelofs The environment we are using is a jboss EAP 6.4 which is running on Windows Server.

Comment: `static volatile` and `synchronized` are **extremely** inefficient, your guess about `static AtomicReference` indeed was correct - atomic variables are efficient and reliable if they're static - but you should keep in mind that some threads may finish before others do, atomic variables do not prevent racing conditions in general, they simply make sure that your field is written entirely before it is read and read entirely before it is being written into. If you want to sequentialize your write-operations you  will need to synchronize or use threadsafe queues

Comment: I'm silly, but I wouldn't think about building something like this myself when there are wonderful tools such as Nagios available.

Comment: From an architecture point of view, I would suggest you to decouple the mail sending from the business program itself. I would suggest you to implement an observer (listener) pattern in your program. You inject the observer into your program. If you detect a failure you notify the observer about the event. The observer then can implement a "semaphore" (date based) to detect whether the mail should be sent or be ignored.